# Secure API access with mobile apps in restricted environments

Tags: api, security, mobile, cloud, vpn

In our current project, IT rules prohibit anything that is not PROD to be publicly accessible from the Internet. Access to development and review environments must be severely restricted. That said, the project also includes mobile apps that are developed together with the cloud-hosted API layer.

In very general terms, what are the common approaches to securing DEV / REVIEW-stage APIs with mobile apps? We've come up with the following ideas:

- IP whitelist on the ingress to the API *(least secure, but easiest to use)*
- VPN gateway to the hosting environment, with corresponding DEV / test devices configuration
- Mutual TLS authentication *(most difficult to implement and operate)*

There are multiple issues to address with each one of the approaches, but I'd like to understand the big picture before diving into any of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## IP Whitelist

> IP whitelist on the in the ingress to the API (least secure, but easiest to use)

I see it as least secure if you are whitelisting IPs that are not exclusive to your company office and/or the the IP is exclusive to your company but used by public WI-fis in your company.

Also in the case you need to whitelist access to remote developers and testers that may or not be in a public IP, this solution will be risky, because people always put convenience in front of security and they may ask to whitelist IPs that are from the coffee shop they like to work from, the shopping mall, the girl friend home, etc..

So I would discard this option, unless you are in a small office where you have the public WI-fi(the one for your clients to use) in a different IP from your main internet connection.

## VPN Gateway

> VPN gateway to the hosting environment, with corresponding DEV / test devices configuration

This approach seems to be the much wise to follow and only who have been granted access to the VPN will be able to use resources hidden behind it, and VPNs can be even used in public WI-fi.

## Mutual TLS Authentication

> Mutual TLS authentication (most difficult to implement and operate)

While is difficult to implement and operate they also suffer of the problem of certificate pinning be possible to bypass.

On [this article](http://blog.approov.io/the-problem-with-pinning) about pinning in mobile apps we can read how easy it can be to implement certificate pinning:

```java
// simplified android example

CertificatePinner certificatePinner = new CertificatePinner.Builder()
       .add("publicobject.com", "sha256/afwiKY3RxoMmLkuRW1l7QsPZTJPwDS2pdDROQjXw8ig=")
       .add("bikewise.org", "sha256/x9SZw6TwIqfmvrLZ/kz1o0Ossjmn728BnBKpUFqGNVM=")
       .build();

OkHttpClient client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
         .certificatePinner(certificatePinner)
         .build();
```

In this same article we can also see how pinning can be a nightmare... as you said, difficult to operate!!!

> The main difficulty with pinning is not technical but operational. By embedding fixed information about the server (the certificate) into the app you create a dependency between the two, as the term pinning implies. This means that whenever you (or your ops team) are planning to change the certificate on the server you must:
>
> - Generate the certificate in advance
> - Build, test and publish a new version of the app with both the new certificate and the old one.
> - Wait for most (80%, 90%, 99% ?) of your users to upgrade to the new version
> - Change the cert on the server
> - Build, test and publish a new version of the app with the old certificate removed.

As if this was not enough, certificate pinning can be by passed by using introspection frameworks, as pointed on the same article I linked above:

> Even if you successfully navigate the operational difficulties inherent in implementing pinning, there is still the giant pink elephant in the room that is unpinning. The development of hooking frameworks such as Xposed has reached such a level of sophistication that a rich ecosystem of modules exists to target various aspects of Android apps including the pinning functionality of HTTP libraries. Using them is very straightforward.

## Another Approach - Going the extra mile

> That said, the project also includes mobile apps that are developed together with the cloud-hosted API layer.

In the context of a mobile apps you can use a technique devised as Mobile App Attestation, that can be used across all environments to protect the API server, for the mobile apps, from responding to requests that are not originated from the genuine mobile app binary you released, signed and registered for that specific environment.

#### Mobile App Attestation

The role of a Mobile App Attestation service is to guarantee at run-time that your mobile app was not tampered or is not running in a rooted device. It consists of a SDK integrated in a your mobile app that runs in the background, without impacting the user experience, and  communicates with a service running in the cloud to attest the integrity of the mobile app and device is running on.

On successful attestation of the mobile app integrity a short time lived JWT token is issued and signed with a secret that only the API server and the Mobile App Attestation service in the cloud are aware. In the case of failure on the mobile app attestation the JWT token is signed with a secret that the API server does not know.

The mobile app must send the JWT token in the headers of the request for very API call it makes. This allows the API server to only serve requests when it can verify the signature and expiration time in the JWT token and refuse them when it fails the verification.

Anyone trying to verify at run-time if a JWT token issued by the Mobile App Attestation is a valid or invalid one will not succeed, because the only difference between them is the secret used to sign it, and this secret is only known at anytime by the Mobile App Attestation service and the API server. This means that even the mobile app is not in possession of the secret, thus is not aware if is sending a valid or invalid JWT token to the API server.

## Conclusion

From your 3 solutions I would go with VPN approach and if you would want to go for the extra mile you should consider implement your own Mobile App Attestation service to guarantee that mobile APIs for any environment only communicate with mobile apps for that specific environment/stage and deny requests from any other source. This solution even allows for your mobile API to be hosted on the public domain without risking leaking any data, thus not needing a VPN on front of it.